# Getting gmail mail read from laravel/php script

Tags: php, laravel, gmail-api

Getting error:

> Error  (400) Precondition check failed.
> google/apiclient: ^1.1

I see some articles where `$client->setSubject("User@mydomain.com");` is necessary but this package has not this method.

```
// Set up Google API client
$client = new Google_Client();

// Load service account JSON file and set up credentials
$credentials = $client->loadServiceAccountJson(config('const.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'), array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'));

$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);

// Check if the access token is expired and refresh it if necessary
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}

// Initialize Gmail Service
$gmailService = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

// Fetch emails
$messages = $gmailService->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', ['q' => 'has:attachment']);

dd("done", $messages); // Output the result for debugging purposes
```

I want to resolve my problem

Comment: The current version of this library is v2.15, and v1.1 is from 2014, so it's probably not reasonable to expect it to still work.

Comment: Did a human being write this code?